# Webform Custom URL ?sid=[submission:sid] does not pick up sid

Tags: webforms

We have redeveloped a website for a company in Wordpress. However, they have a complex Drupal 7 webform that must be used on the website. We have chosen to place the Drupal installation with webform in a subfolder of the Wordpress website.
**This works fine on the 2 test servers.** However, on the main server where the website is being deployed, the Drupal webform is not working correctly. So the issue is specific to a server.

Here is a summary of the problem:

- The user fills out the webform and submits.
- Calculations are done, and all user data is correctly registered in the Drupal back-end in Content/ Webforms/ Submissions. (ok to this point)
- However, the front-end should then redirect to a results page. This is done by setting the Custom URL field to: node/177?sid=[submission:sid]. As far as I can see, the sid value is not being picked up (it is empty).
- A confirmation email is also sent to the user, but calculated values in the email are unpopulated.

The code that is not picking up the sid is below (taken from a file called node--177.tpl.php ):

```
<?php
module_load_include('inc', 'webform', 'includes/webform.submissions');
if(isset($_GET['error'])){
    $error = 'Veuillez réessayer';
}else{
    if(isset($_GET['sid'])){
        $sid = $_GET['sid'];
...
```

So on test servers sid is populated. On the production server it is empty.

I have looked all over for the solution, and cannot find the problem. I can only think it is related to being in a sub-folder.

It may also be indicative of the problem, I observered that the  tag displays correctly on the test servers, but on the production server it is empty.

Has anyone come across an issue like this?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show some code? How are calculations being performed? When you say the calculated data appear in the back end, where do you see them? As a webform submission? You mention porting the site to a sub-domain, but you also mention a sub-folder. Can you explain this relationship?

Comment: @Beau I added the information as per your request.I hope it is clear.

Comment: For anyone who come across this, I fixed it. It was something related to the being within a subfolder and the server settings. Once I moved it to a root directory on the same server, the problem resolved.